# future_map not finding global values when running in multisession

Tags: r, r-future, furrr

I'm trying to understand how to pass in `future_map` a list of character vectors in `.x` that is evaluated by `.f`. In the code below, I feed `bestVars` (a list of variable vectors) to `.x` which in turn passes each element of the list to a custom function, `run_sim_in_par`. The custom function then uses `mget(.x)` to get the values of each variable in `.x` from the globals and then `Reduce`s these values and finally performs a few other steps.

When I attempt to run the `run_sims_in_par` function in multisession I keep getting:

> Error in (function (.x, .f, ..., .progress = FALSE)  :    ℹ In index:
>
> 1. Caused by error: ! value for 'a1' not found

After reading several questions and other sources on this error, I understand that it's not possible to automatically identify global variables specified via a character string (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future/vignettes/future-4-issues.html). In my example, what is the proper way to have `future_map` get global values referenced in `.x` using a list of character vectors? I've been unsuccessful in the many different ways I've set `globals` and `options` arguments.

The workaround suggested in the future vignette link above recommends the following:

```
The workaround is to tell the future framework what additional globals are needed. This can be done via argument globals using:

> f <- future(my_sum("a"), globals = structure(TRUE, add = "a"))
> y <- value(f)
> y
[1] 6
or by injecting variable a at the beginning of the future expression, e.g.

> f <- future({ a; my_sum("a") })
> y <- value(f)
> y
[1] 6
```

But I'm having a hard time understanding how to modify my code based on the suggested action.

I'm sure this will come up so I'll pre-emptively mention it: the reason I'm assigning the `df` values to my global environment is because I'm trying to lower the size of the globals exported by `future` as this is significantly slowing the code when running multisession on remote AWS clusters.

```
library(future)
library(furrr)
library(kit)
library(tidyverse)

## reprex data
vars <- paste0(letters,1:10)
bestVars <- combn(vars, 5, simplify = F)
df <- data.frame(
  matrix(data = rnorm(50000*length(vars),200,500), nrow = 50000, ncol = length(vars))
)
names(df) <- vars
df$value <- rnorm(n = nrow(df), 350, 300)
df <- df %>%
  dplyr::select(value,everything(.))
df <- lapply(split.default(x = df, names(df)), function(x) x[[1]])

list2env(df, globalenv())

rm(df)

run_sim_in_par <- function(vars_to_sim)
{
  sampled_rows <- sample(x = 1:length(value), size = 50, replace = F)
  varname <- paste(names(vars_to_sim), collapse = "*")
  best <- Reduce(vars_to_sim, f = '*')[sampled_rows]
  row_idx <- kit::topn(best, n = 5, decreasing = T, hasna = FALSE, index = TRUE)
  
  best_row_value <- value[sampled_rows][row_idx]
  
  sim <- data.frame(var = varname,
                    mean_value = mean(best_row_value))
  return(sim)
}

## working when explicitly declaring .x
x <- bestVars[[1]]
simulated_res <- run_sim_in_par(vars_to_sim = mget(x))

## not recognizing .x
simulated_res <- future_map_dfr(
  .x = bestVars,
  .f = ~run_sim_in_par(vars_to_sim = mget(.x))
)

# Error in (function (.x, .f, ..., .progress = FALSE)  : 
#             ℹ In index: 1.
#           Caused by error:
#             ! value for 'a1' not found

## same erro when setting furr_options for 'globals'
simulated_res <- future_map_dfr(
  .x = bestVars,
  .f = ~run_sim_in_par(vars_to_sim = mget(.x)),
  .options = furrr_options(globals = TRUE) 
)

## attempt at declaring all globals for just the first element of bestVars
simulated_res <- future_map_dfr(
  .x = bestVars[[1]],
  .f = ~run_sim_in_par(vars_to_sim = mget(.x)),
  .options = furrr_options(globals = c(bestVars[[1]], "run_sim_in_par", "value"))
)

# Error in (function (.x, .f, ..., .progress = FALSE)  : 
#             ℹ In index: 1.
#           Caused by error:
#             ! value for 'a1' not found
```

Comment: This might go against what you mentioned about globals, but can you keep `df` as a data frame (bind it back after the `lapply`, or call `purrr::map_dfc` or something)? In that case, you can call `run_sim_in_par` on each item in `bestVars`, then get the corresponding vectors (a1, b2, etc) like `df[, var_names]`. That bypasses the need for `mget`.

Comment: That's basically what I'm doing now which is to keep the `df` in a list of column vectors, feed `bestVars` to `.x`, and then get the corresponding values from the `df` elements via a second argument in `run_sim_in_par`. But my real `df` list is a very large file (>40gb) and the overheard with transferring an entire list to my aws cluster kills any speed gains from running the function remotely. This is the reason why I want to try assigning the `df` elements to the globals so that I'm transferring batches of small files to my cluster instead of a very large list. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: It looks like you are hoping to copy only variables needed by an iteration to the core executing that iteration? I believe this is only possible if you iterate over these sets of variables (i.e., split the data accordingly and iterate over these splits). If you don't want that, you could try creating a "shared object": https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/SharedObject.html

Comment: @Roland that's exactly what I was trying to do to test out if I could get around the data transfer overhead with uploading large files to the cluster. The `SharedObject`package looks very promising from a first read. I'll read more on it and do some local testing. Do you have experience using this library in conjuction with the `futures` package? Are there any SO posts or other sources you can share that you think are useful in this context?

Comment: How tied are you to keeping the values in lists? Especially at the size you're talking about, would it be better to load the data frame into a database on AWS, and work with it from there? It's starting to seem like more of a data management issue than a futures issue. That could also allow you to do the operation in chunks

Comment: @camille I'm not tied to either (list or df). My 1st code started out in a df and as I made changes to try and speed up the `run_in_sim_par` and decrease the globals size, I ended up with the list of columns format. I think you may be right that this may be more of a data management hurdle as it appears this version of the code just may not be feasible with `future_map` after all. And that is fine, I didn't expect it to be this difficult when I first started going down this approach but it appears that `future_map` is just not really set up to work how I'm trying to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You are just missing a `, inherits = TRUE` in the `mget` here. (Without it, `mget` (in contrast to `get` (by default)), it will only search the current enviroment calling mget ( which in your direct test happens to be the global env - the same env containing your variables).
The correct title of the question would thus be: "mget not finding global variables when called from child enviroment", `(function(){x <- bestVars[[1]]; simulated_res <- run_sim_in_par(vars_to_sim = mget(x))})())` fails with `Error: value for ‘a1’ not found` too)

But the globals available during future evaluation are the same for each iteration of `future_map_dfr` even if not every iteration needs all of them. Thus, you don't save anything by adding them to globals individually. You could, however, work around that limitation by replacing `future_map_dfr` by your own variant that uses separate globals for each iteration:

```
simulated_res <- lapply(bestVars, function(vars_to_sim) future(run_sim_in_par(vars_to_sim = mget(vars_to_sim, inherits =TRUE)),  globals = vars_to_sim))
simulated_res <- lapply(simulated_res, future::value)
simulated_res <- dplyr::bind_rows(simulated_res)
```

But this will not help at all here, because the number of columns is small compared to the combinations of columns that you iterate over.

Make sure your data is transferred only once to each worker - use manual chunking and a nested loop inside each iteration if necessary. (EDIT: this only apply to the batchtools backends, with `plan(multisession)` and `furrr:furrr_options(scheduling=1)` (the default) this is the case already)

Comment: my actual problem is similar to my example but the `df` and `bestVars` lists are significantly bigger (`bestVars` can be 50-60 million elements of variable combos). Hence, I think my code is quite optimized as I've spent a lot of time vectorizing the guts of the `run_sim_in_par` function. The main overheard now is simply the sheer number of variable combinations, hence my attempt to run it remotely on aws. When you say `When working in the future-verse, I often load data within the futures`, can you please share some helpful sources in your answer so I can read up on how to do this?

Comment: continued...I will try your solutions locally and test it out. However, understanding now that `globals available during future evaluation are the same for each iteration...even if not every iteration needs all of them` I'm less hopeful than I was when I first made my OP.

Comment: After looking into the function itself a bit more i change my answer a bit make these questions obsolete i think. 50-60 million combinations would correspond to 4h, If you need it only once, run it overnight and save the results...

Comment: I can run the first line but the second line fails for me with `Error in run_sim_in_par(vars_to_sim = mget(vars_to_sim, inherits = TRUE)) : could not find function "run_sim_in_par"`.  However, the proposed answer does not use `future_map` as I noted in my OP and I need to stick to `future_map` so that I can use the code in `multisession` on remote clusters.

Comment: Obviously this is meant to run after your mwe code (after the `## not recognizing .x` line) and works just fine.

Comment: Also the first paragraph solves the error you got, doesn't it?

Comment: no, your code isn't working. neither suggestion is working as I already mentioned. Maybe it works for you locally but it doesn't for me: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oTMR-5EKWYSPfkdwHBHBVM8xZr5JMeR9/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: Just adding the missing `inherts=TRUE`: https://gist.github.com/jan-glx/5cba1f420bf8a7d07cc7a1fce00ce336 one future per comb: https://gist.github.com/jan-glx/ade50aa60b586d6d2400eb90cc8baf8c

Comment: i got access to your *screenshots* now. The 1st solution is missing the `, inherits = TRUE` it is all about. for the second solution it seems that you forgot to evaluate the run_sim_in_par assignement becaus you ran it within the debugger but then quit the debugger. ... (the gist i shared above (created with `reprexr`) contain some code about random seeds that allows to get the same results with the different methods)

Comment: I hope my answers helped with your problem even if just giving the proof that using per iteration globals won't help in your scenario & just wanted to let you know that I won't spend more time it

Answer (score 1):

In my other answer I showed how to solve the error message and how to get control which globals are available for each future. Here I give hints how to speedup your computations in general.

One thing that helps a lot is not computing the product for all the not sampled rows:

```
set.seed(1)

vars <- paste0(letters,1:10)

bestVars <- combn(vars, 5, simplify = F)
names(bestVars) <- sapply(bestVars, paste, collapse = "*")

df <- data.frame(
  matrix(data = rnorm(50000*length(vars),200,500), nrow = 50000, ncol = length(vars))
)
names(df) <- vars
df$value <- rnorm(n = nrow(df), 350, 300)

N <- nrow(df)
run_sim_in_par <- function(vars_to_sim)
{
  sampled_rows <- sample(x = N, size = 50, replace = F)
  
  vars_to_sim = df[sampled_rows, vars_to_sim]
  
  best <- Reduce(vars_to_sim, f = '*')
  row_idx <- head(order(-best), n = 5)  # head(order(best), n = 5) #kit::topn(best, n = 5, decreasing = T, hasna = FALSE, index = TRUE)
  
  best_row_value <- df[sampled_rows[row_idx], "value"]
  
  mean(best_row_value)
}

stime <- Sys.time()
simulated_res <- sapply(bestVars, run_sim_in_par)
simulated_res <- data.frame(var=names(simulated_res), mean = as.vector(simulated_res))
tail(simulated_res)
#>                  var     mean
#> 65775 u1*v2*w3*x4*y5 438.0177
#> 65776 u1*v2*w3*x4*z6 543.4459
#> 65777 u1*v2*w3*y5*z6 520.7860
#> 65778 u1*v2*x4*y5*z6 226.6832
#> 65779 u1*w3*x4*y5*z6 307.0623
#> 65780 v2*w3*x4*y5*z6 493.8572
Sys.time()-stime
#> Time difference of 15.72114 secs
```

Comment: @On_an_island did this solve the problem, or get you more of the way there? If so I'll award the bounty

Comment: This solution again moves away from `future_map` and uses `sapply`. I would like to stick with the `furrr` library as `future_map` on remote clusters has been the fastest solution for me on the current version of my working code.

Comment: 1. the key message of this answer (compute the product only for the sampled rows) is applicable  to what ever method you use to loop over the combinations.
2. I am sure sapply is much faster than future_map for this problem. If it isn't for your actual problem please post about something closer to your actual problem.
3. consider chunking the iterations, nesting this sapply solution within future_map

Comment: yes, your first point is valid and understood. About your second point, how did you come to this conclusion? See this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rD4c0wV8VWL77qJxy7NrR4vXC4rjrmvR/view?usp=drive_link    `future_map` more than 2x faster than `sapply` for this problem.

Comment: great to see that combining parallelization through future multisession with trick of this answer gives another speedup! I somehow had in the back of my mind that future.apply would need to transfer the data for every job (when you would expect it to be much slower for such a not so compute intensive task) but it seems that's not the case. Maybe I was thinking of this issue https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future.batchtools/issues/36#issuecomment-651426279 that might affect you too. Can you edit this answer to use your futureverse sapply equivalent approach?

Comment: @On_an_island are you using future.batchtools? are you using future.chunk.size  ? Otherwise a new LSF-job and thus a new registry will be created for each combination (meaning the data is copied for each), use `future.chunk.size=length(comb)/number_of_workers_you_have_in_your_cluster`

Answer (score 0):

```
library(future)
library(furrr)
library(kit)
library(tidyverse)

# Reproducible data generation
set.seed(123)

vars <- paste0(letters, 1:10)
bestVars <- combn(vars, 5, simplify = FALSE)

df <- data.frame(
  matrix(data = rnorm(50000 * length(vars), 200, 500), nrow = 50000, ncol = length(vars))
)
names(df) <- vars
df$value <- rnorm(n = nrow(df), 350, 300)
df <- df %>%
  dplyr::select(value, everything())
df <- lapply(split.default(x = df, names(df)), function(x) x[[1]])

list2env(df, globalenv())

rm(df)

# Explicitly declare the global variables used in run_sim_in_par
globals <- c("value")

run_sim_in_par <- function(vars_to_sim)
{
  # Set the seed for reproducibility
  set.seed(123)
  
  # Extract value from the global environment
  value <- get("value", envir = .GlobalEnv)
  
  # Make sure each variable in vars_to_sim is available globally
  for (var in vars_to_sim) {
    assign(var, as.numeric(get(var, envir = .GlobalEnv)), envir = .GlobalEnv)
  }
  
  sampled_rows <- sample(x = 1:length(value), size = 50, replace = FALSE)
  varname <- paste(names(vars_to_sim), collapse = "*")
  best <- Reduce('*', lapply(vars_to_sim, function(var) as.numeric(get(var, envir = .GlobalEnv))))[sampled_rows]
  row_idx <- kit::topn(best, n = 5, decreasing = TRUE, hasna = FALSE, index = TRUE)
  
  best_row_value <- value[sampled_rows][row_idx]
  
  sim <- data.frame(var = varname,
                    mean_value = mean(best_row_value))
  return(sim)
}

# Use future_map_dfr with furrr_options to pass the globals and set seed
simulated_res <- future_map_dfr(
  .x = bestVars,
  .f = ~run_sim_in_par(vars_to_sim = .x),
  .options = furrr_options(
    globals = c("value", "run_sim_in_par"),
    seed = TRUE
  )
)

# View the results
  ls(simulated_res)
  head(simulated_res)
  var mean_value
1     196.645210
2     178.927198
3       9.733175
4     106.984018
5     372.041245
6     378.836707
```

Comment: testing your answer as is I get `"Error in (function (.x, .f, ..., .progress = FALSE)  :  ℹ In index: 1. Caused by error in run_sim_in_par(): ! could not find function "run_sim_in_par"`.  If I add the `run_sim_in_par` func like this: `.options = furrr_options(globals = c("run_sim_in_par",globals), seed = TRUE)` I get the my initial error: `Error in (function (.x, .f, ..., .progress = FALSE)  : ℹ In index: 1. Caused by error in `get()`: ! object 'a1' not found`. Declaring my fun like this: `globals <- c("value","run_sim_in_par")` with no other changes, still getting `object 'a1' not found`

Comment: Can u update your R and R studio

Comment: Or I edited code, can u try with this new updated code

Comment: try also this one globals <- c("value", "run_sim_in_par", "a1")

Comment: `globals <- c("value", "run_sim_in_par", "a1")` won't work because the variable combinations change as per my `bestVars` list. For ex: element 1 has: `"a1" "b2" "c3" "d4" "e5"`. I can't manually declare each variable like that. I just want `future_map` to automatically get the value for each `.x` from the global environment.

Comment: i updated R to most recent version 4.3.2 and my RStudio is the most recent version (2023.12.0) and I still get the same error: `Caused by error in `get()`:
! object 'a1' not found`